# SSRS matrix pivot

Tags: reporting-services, dynamic, matrix, pivot

I have following structure:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3  
---------------
F     P    R1
F     P    R2
F     P    R3
F     P    R4
```

Col3 values can be anything.  Now I want, in following format, only the top 3:

```
Col1 Col2 Res1 Res2 Res3  
------------------------------
F     P    R1   R2   R3
```

I tried it using Matrix, but I m not able to separate the result as 3 columns.
Basically, the end user opens this report in Excel and applies filter and sorting to it.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest editing the filter on the grouping of col3 - as follows:

1. Right-click on the Tablix and select Properties.
2. Select the Groups tab from the Matrix Properties dialog.
3. In the Columns section of the Groups tab, select the grouping for col3 and then click the  (lower) Edit... button.
4. In the Grouping and Sorting Properties dialog, select the Filters tab.
5. Add a new expression for COL3.Value, with the Operator TopN and the Value 3.
6. Click OK on the Grouping and Sorting Properties dialog, and then click OK on the Matrix Properties dialog.